# Color of Light Channel in LAB Colorspace

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, lab-color-space

I have a doubt in lab color space. I admit that I have little knowledge in the field of image processing and I'm trying to learn while doing the project simultaneously. I've searched a lot in the net but couldn't find answer to my doubt and hence I'm posting by doubt here

```
sharpImageLab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(sharpImage)
```

So in the above piece of code I converted the RGB image into lab color space image and I tried getting light channel by writing the following piece of code

```
sharpImageLightChannel = []
row, col = sharpImageLab.shape[0], sharpImageLab.shape[1]
for i in range(0, row):
    eachrowList = []
    for j in range(0, col):
        eachrowList.append(sharpImageLab[i][j][0])
    sharpImageLightChannel.append(eachrowList)
```

I know that it(getting the light channel) can be done in a single line of code but I'm not very much used to numpy library so, I've done it in a trivial method

**my doubt** : I tried displaying the light channel of image and I thought it would be a grayscale kind of image but to my surprise I'm still seeing colors in that image.

[image: output of Light channel]

I have also read in wikipedia that perpectual lightness is in between 0 to 100 where 0 stands for black and 100 stands for white

Can someone explain me the reason for getting a colour image for light channel?..Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')` to display the image. By default, colormap is not gray

Comment: It uses `colormap='viridis'` by default, you need `cmap='gray'` for greyscale images.

Comment: ohh...thanks a lot guys..I'm sorry for asking such a trivial question.. I'm new to python